# how to make clang compile to LLVM IR with textual labels for simple function

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Hello I have to parse some LLVM IR code for a compiler course. I am very new to LLVM. 
I have clang and LLVM on my computer, and when I compile a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printf("Stuff!\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

using command: `clang -cc1 test.c -emit-llvm`

I get llvm IR with what I believe are called implicit blocks:

`; <label>:4                                       ; preds = %9, %0`

However my parser also needs to handle llvm IR with textual labels:

`for.cond:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %entry`

My problem is that I do not know how to generate such IR and was hoping someone show me how. 
I tried Google and such, but I couldn't find appropriate information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is no longer valid. Nor is it a good way to achieve the stated.
In case someone stumbles upon this question, like I did, I'm providing the answer.

```
clang-8 -S -fno-discard-value-names -emit-llvm test.c
```

Answer (score 1):

use this site with `Show detailed bytecode analysis` checked

http://ellcc.org/demo/index.cgi

Comment: and optimization level none.